# Как парсить сайт в ответах на запросы нет Html

Tags: javascript, java, html, парсер, jsoup

Есть сайт bpmonline.com   Хотел распарсить, но  на мои запросы возвращается значения полей не в текстовом виде, а в виде каких то значений, которые поймет только разработчик сайта. Т.е. значение поля 455 и дальше уже это конвертируется в текстовое значение. Я так понимаю за такое отвечает javascipt. И действительно при каждом  запросе отрабатывает много скриптов.
 Но мне как то нужно получить этот html, но думаю это не правильный путь, пытаться получить html.. как поступают в таких случаях?

Comment: Как вариант, в таких случаях берут Selenium.

Comment: Dmitry, слышал мельком про эту штуку. Не подскажите в чем его основная фишка? Я так понимаю она заключается в том, что ему доступен html код страницы открытый в браузере? Просто я думал получить этот Html , но ведь наверняка есть в временной папке в винде, но доступа к файлу все равно не будет пока его браузер использует. А вот силениум наверно имеет доступ?

Comment: И если да, то возможно ли с помощью него не только прочитать html но править его?

Comment: Фишка jsoup в том, что он прикидывается браузером (для сервера, который вас интересует). Фишка Selenium - в том, что он он запускает *настоящий* браузер и просто им командует.

Comment: Dmitry, спасибо, коротко и ясно. Я вижу, что вебдрайвер используется в основном для тестов, но ведь не обязательно делать тесты? Я ведь смогу запустить браузер, и тест на этом не закончится. Дальше я перейду вручную на нужную страницу и по команде(комбинация клавиш, слушаю клавиатуру) в html странички вставляю нужный мне текст. ? Это ведь реализуемо посредством вебдрайвера?

Comment: Или например я запущу нужную мне страницу и мой код будет в браузере перезапускать эту страницу через опр. интервал времени, проверять появились ли нужные мне элементы?

Comment: Мне представляется всё это возможным. И если это так, то не проще будет это же реализовать с помощью расширения для браузера? Я просто ищу более простой путь, чтобы мог с страницы получать html (это чтобы проверить появились ли новые элементы) и чтобы мог в html страницы добавлять свой текст.

Comment: Вы таки будете смеяться, но изначально селениум и возник как плагин к фаерфоксу. Никакого программирования, просто кликая мышой надо было задавать последовательность действий. И только потом сделали библиотеку для java, C#, pyhon и прочих. И конечно, все, что вы выше писали, можно в нем сделать.

Comment: Прикольно, прикольно)) значит я могу не использовать этого монстра, а написать разобраться с тем как написать свое расширение идеальное под мой случай)  Но..есть одна проблемка, из-за которой придется выбирать силениум. Я парсю сайт посредством java программы, т.е. данные которые надо вставить  в поля сайта, хранятся в java в переменных и возможно ли без извращений передать их расширению хрома, например, я не знаю. Если ответите и на этот вопрос, то это расставило бы все точки над i. Можно ли передать данные из java в расширение браузера

Comment: Подойдет даже вариант такой: я записываю данные после парсинга на жесткий диск, а расширение их оттуда грузит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74527/discussion-between-dmitry-and-turalllb).